# How to start VMware VIX on ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, vmware

I have installed VMware VIX on Ubuntu 14.04 with the help of ubuntu forums. But I don't know how to start GUI for the same. Is there any command to start the GUI or script to run. I used below method to install VMware:

```
apt-get install build-essential linux-headers-`uname -r`
```

Downloaded `Vmware-VIX-1.12.3-1410761.i386.bundle` to `~/Downloads` and then:

```
sh ~/Downloads/Vmware-VIX-1.12.3-1410761.i386.bundle
```

Then it prompted GUI to install everything went smoothly, it did not give any error.

Any ideas how do I get the graphical interface?

Comment: Just to clarify - What is your host machine and what is your guest machine?

Comment: I am yet to create a guest/virtual machine. Host is ubuntu 14

Comment: If you click up on the applications menu and type 'VM' or 'ware' does it show up in the search results?

Comment: no have  already tried to search, what you have mentioned

Comment: Can you edit your original post to link to the instructions you used to install? Also, see if the 'patch' at this link might be  useful to you: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/06/how-to-install-vmware-player-in-ubuntu.html

Comment: Are you actually just trying to install, run and manage VM's or any special use case for VIX?